# C# list.remove throwing enumeration operation error in foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have looked at multiple SO questions related to mine, as well as Googling, and I have been unable to find a solution that works for me.

Given a list of files, I am trying to cull all the non-cs ones, for reasons.  I take the string array, convert to list, and iterate over the list, removing all the files I don't want by using list.Remove().

After the first removal, it errors out with

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute
```

The code is:

```
string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);

                //Converting to list, to use list.Remove rather than rewriting entire array at each delete
                var list = new List<string>(files);
                foreach (string readFile in list)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(readFile) != ".cs") //|| Path.GetExtension(readFile) != ".dll")
                    {
                        //remove, as we don't currently care about non cs files.
                        list.Remove(readFile);
                    }
                }

                //Converting back to string array for use in the rest of the program
                files = list.ToArray();
            }
```

I have also tried RemoteAt(), which produces the same error.

```
string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);

                //Converting to list, to use list.Remove rather than rewriting entire array at each delete
                var list = new List<string>(files);
                int i = 0;
                for(int i=0; i<list.Count();i++)
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(readFile) != ".cs") //|| Path.GetExtension(readFile) != ".dll")
                    {
                        //remove, as we don't currently care about non cs files.
                        list.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                //Converting back to string array for use in the rest of the program
                files = list.ToArray();
            }
```

Any recommendations for overcoming this error, as some of the directories will have over 500 files in them, and I want to avoid rewriting the string array as much as possible.

I have read the following SO questions:

[How to remove item from list in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018957/how-to-remove-item-from-list-in-c)

[C# error Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599864/c-sharp-error-collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execute)

[Enumerations Foreach Loop C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545482/enumerations-foreach-loop-c-sharp)

["List.Remove" in C# does not remove item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971167/list-remove-in-c-sharp-does-not-remove-item)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you only want `*.cs`, you can pass that to [`GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_).

Comment: Or you can replace your for-loop with a quick LINQ expression, something like `return files.Where(t=>Path.GetExtension(t) == ".cs").ToArray();`

Comment: XY problem. @Blorgbeard got the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change

```
foreach (string readFile in list)
```

to

```
foreach (string readFile in list.ToList())
```

it works.

My guess is that the list.Remove alters the original list, and invalidates the enumeration.

Comment: "*My guess is that the list.Remove alters the original list, and invalidates the enumeration.*" -- this is correct

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a for loop in reverse order so that removed entries do not effect the loop.

```
for (int x = list.Count-1; x >= 0; x--)
{
  string readFile = list[x];
  // ...
  list.Remove(readFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [RemoveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.8) method on `List`:

```
list.RemoveAll(readFile => Path.GetExtension(readFile) != ".cs");
```

This will remove everything that matches your predicate, and will return the number of items it removed.